# function checkusername() is alerting but i dont want it to

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I call `checkusername()`, it alerts. But why it alerts when I call `markcheck()`?

I am using `checkbutton =1` as a flag and I also used a condition `if checkbutton==1`. It should not alert, but it is still alerting.

If anyone thinks this function can be minified. Please minify this:

```
<script>
var checkbut = 0;
function markcheck()
{
    checkbut = "1";
    checkusername();
}
function checkusername()
{

var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'saves/checkusername.php',
    data: {
        username: username
    },
    beforeSend: function()
    {
        document.getElementById("checkbutton").innerHTML = "Checking";
        setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("checkbutton").innerHTML = "Check Availiblity";},1000);
    },
    success: function(data) 
    {

        if (data == "1")
        {
            document.getElementById("taken").innerHTML = "This Username is already taken. Choose a new one.";
            document.getElementById("username").className = "form-control form-control-danger";
            document.getElementById("labelusername").style.color = "red";
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("labelusername").style.color = "";
            document.getElementById("taken").innerHTML = "";
            if (data == "0")
            {
                if (checkbut == "0")
                {
                    alert('ujhygtfrd');
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
})
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please, use https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for code minimization!

Comment: `var checkbutton = "1";` is a **local** variable. it only exists inside of `markcheck()`. Please read on varible scopes in JS

Comment: Also your using jQuery, use `$('#id')` instead of the `document.getElementById`

Comment: @Ikillnukes Minification shouldn't be a goal on itself. Write the code readable and jack it through a minifier afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set **checkbutton** variable outside of your **markcheck()** function!

Instead of this:

```
function markcheck()
{
    var checkbutton = "1";
    checkusername();
}
```

This:

```
var checkbutton = "1";
function markcheck()
{
    checkusername();
}
```

Or like this:

```
var checkbutton;
function markcheck()
{
    checkbutton = "1"
    checkusername();
}
```

This happens because, the **variable checkbutton** is inside of the **local scope** of the **checkmark function** and it get erased when the **markcheck()** ends.

Comment: i am only calling either checkusername() or markcheck(), so if i create var checkbutton outside of function var will not create

Comment: @sidhant no, the variable will be available for all the functions and also, for other js files.

Comment: If you choose the second option is true that else case will be called always, unless you modify the checkbutton variable.

Comment: i had edited the question. plz check it now .  the problem is still there both button are alerting

Comment: And where do you call the markcheck()??? I don't see that the value can change because you don't call it. Also, please, use ints better than strings...

Answer (score 1):

Your variable is inside of function put it outside make it global so that other functions can access its value define it outside of function

```
var checkButton;
function checkMark(){
  checkButton = "1";
  anotherFunction();
}

function anotherFunction(){
 if(checkButton=="1"){
   return 0;
 }else{
 alert("yeah its value is not 1");
 }
}
```

Comment: The user is telling that else case is getting called always.